# Fixing duplicate customers in SQL

Tags: sql, database, duplicates

I am using java on sql server and I have a DB problem of duplicate customers
 (many customers are duplicated in the following way).
My tables are :

```
CUSTOMER(person_id,customer_id)
ORDER (order_id,person_id )
```

and a duplicated customer looks like this :

```
CUSTOMER(333,040535743)
CUSTOMER(334,040535743)
CUSTOMER(335,040535743)

ORDER (1,333 )
ORDER (2,333 )

ORDER (4,334 )
ORDER (5,334 )
ORDER (6,334 )

ORDER (7,335 )
ORDER (8,335 )
ORDER (9,335 )


CUSTOMER(336,009530650)
CUSTOMER(337,009530650)

ORDER (10,336 )
ORDER (11,336 )
ORDER (12,336 )

ORDER (13,337 )
ORDER (14,337 )
ORDER (15,337 )
```

333,334,335 are three rows for the same customer because they have the same customer_id, I want to keep only the last customer ( 335), and make all the orders of 334 and 333 refer to 333.

my final data should be :

```
CUSTOMER(335,040535743)
ORDER (1,335)
ORDER (2,335)

ORDER (4,335)
ORDER (5,335)
ORDER (6,335)

ORDER (7,335 )
ORDER (8,335 )
ORDER (9,335 )



CUSTOMER(337,009530650)

ORDER (10,337)
ORDER (11,337)
ORDER (12,337)

ORDER (13,337 )
ORDER (14,337 )
ORDER (15,337 )
```

how do I do a query that does that for all my duplicated customers? (I have a query returning the list of the customer_id's that have duplications)

Comment: Is there any Foreign Key constraint between the 2 tables?

Comment: even if there is I can remove the constraint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `Order` table:

```
UPDATE o
SET o.person_id = cc.max_person_id
FROM
    [Order] AS o
  JOIN
    Customer AS c
        ON c.person_id = o.person_id
  JOIN
    ( SELECT customer_id
           , MAX(person_id) AS max_person_id
      FROM Customer
      GROUP BY customer_id
    ) AS cc
        ON cc.customer_id = c.customer_id ;
```

Then, update the `Customer` table:

```
UPDATE c
SET c.person_id = cc.max_person_id
FROM
    Customer AS c
  JOIN
    ( SELECT customer_id
           , MAX(person_id) AS max_person_id
      FROM Customer
      GROUP BY customer_id
    ) AS cc
        ON cc.customer_id = c.customer_id ;
```

---

After that, it would be good to have `Customer(person_id)` defined as `PRIMARY KEY` or with a `UNIQUE` constraint.

And a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint from `Order(person_id)` to `Customer(person_id)`

Comment: Thanks!, the first query did the job, I didnt need the second one though, I just delete all the customers that dont have the maximal person id

Comment: Yes, right, the second statement should be `DELETE`, not `UPDATE`.

Answer (score -2):

start with this:

```
select person_id from customer where customer_id = 040535743
```

then something like:

```
select * from orders where person id in ( select person_id from customer where customer_id = 040535743 )
```

then you can play with MAX person_id in the results.

Comment: notice that I have MANY duplicated customers like the examples I gave. its not a problem for 1 customer

Comment: then the suggestion is to play with MAX and GROUP BY on this basic structure

Comment: I added a more precise explanation of what I want